# asp control fires javascript but my function is undefined

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I was testing my ASP code, and have the handlers fire correctly but when executing my javascript function it gives an undefined error.

When working with ASP is there something going on with the post back or limbo-like state where Javascript is undefined?

To test i had my test go like this:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" onchange="alert('this is a test'); numsOnly();"></asp:textbox>
```

Could it be a syntax thing?  should i say onchange="return numsOnly();" instead?  The alert shows that it does fire, but the function  numsOnly(); is defined in the head of the page

Comment: If the browser says the function is not defined, then it's not defined. That could be because it's declaration is such that it's not global, or it could be due to an error in the JavaScript block wherein the function is declared.

Comment: Yep. If you're calling `numsOnly()` inline on an element then it must be defined in the global scope; i.e. on the `window` object.

Comment: You have tagged this asp-classic but it appears to be asp.net; if so you should re-tag to get the correct audience. What you have should work; you need to edit your question with the appropriate parts of rendered output of the page

Comment: es, i will re-tag it.  Ill double-check the scope to see what is going on and ill post more information as it comes in.

Comment: Scope fixed, problem resolved.   An else without and brackets caused an error.  +1 to Chris and Pointy for Pointy'ing out the yellow brick road to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had noticed that i had the following line of code:

```
if (x[11] == "top" && x[12] == "left") { $("#toggle_1").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else if (x[12] == "top" && x[11] == "middle") { $("#toggle_2").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else if (x[12] == "top" && x[11] == "right") { $("#toggle_3").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else if (x[12] == "middle" && x[11] == "left") { $("#toggle_4").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else if (x[12] == "middle" && x[11] == "middle") { $("#toggle_5").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else if (x[12] == "middle" && x[11] == "right") { $("#toggle_6").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else if (x[12] == "bottom" && x[11] == "left") { $("#toggle_7").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else if (x[12] == "bottom" && x[11] == "middle") { $("#toggle_8").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else if (x[12] == "bottom" && x[11] == "right") { $("#toggle_9").attr("checked", "true"); }
        else alert("None of the alignments were matched");
```

I also noticed that the alert statement, was commented out as I dont need to know that information all the time now.
It looked like:

```
else if (x[12] == "bottom" && x[11] == "right") { $("#toggle_9").attr("checked", "true"); }
else //alert("None of the alignments were matched");
```

which fails the javascript test, as it is looking to execute something which isnt there, and read the closing bracket as a part of code, and an error.

It was easily resolved by adding the following 2 characters, {  and  }.

```
else if (x[12] == "bottom" && x[11] == "right") { $("#toggle_9").attr("checked", "true"); }
    else { alert("None of the alignments were matched"); }
```

Problem solved. Sorry for the issue.  Will +1 people who helped point me in the direction as ultimately i was looking for something and noticed an intellisense error which confirmed what they said.